# Mac OS ssh: Connection reset by peer

Tags: ssh, macos

To work with Hadoop, I edited the hosts file and deletе some lines (these lines interfered with correct operation). When running `ssh localhost`, I encountered the error:

```
kex_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
```

Configuration:

- `hosts.allow`:

  ```
  sshd : ALL
  ALL : ALL
  ```
- `hosts.deny`:

  ```
  sshd: ALL
  ```
- `hosts`:

  ```
  ##
  # Host Database
  #
  # localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
  # when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
  ##
  127.0.0.1   localhost
  255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
  ::1             localhost
  ```
- `ls -ld /etc /etc/ssh* /etc/ssh*/*`:

  ```
  lrwxr-xr-x@  1 root  wheel      11  1 янв  2020 /etc -> private/etc
  drwxrwxr-x  13 root  wheel     416  2 окт 23:26 /etc/ssh
  -rwxrwxr-x   1 root  wheel  577388  1 янв  2020 /etc/ssh/moduli
  -rwxrwxr-x   1 root  wheel    1511  1 янв  2020 /etc/ssh/ssh_config
  -rwxrwxr-x   1 root  wheel    1405 22 ноя 18:22 /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
  -rwxrwxr-x   1 root  wheel     620 22 ноя 18:22 /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key.pub
  -rwxrwxr-x   1 root  wheel     525 22 ноя 18:23 /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
  -rwxrwxr-x   1 root  wheel     192 22 ноя 18:23 /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key.pub
  -rwxrwxr-x   1 root  wheel     387  2 окт 23:26 /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
  -rwxrwxr-x   1 root  wheel      82  2 окт 23:26 /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key.pub
  -rwxrwxr-x   1 root  wheel    2622 22 ноя 18:22 /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
  -rwxrwxr-x   1 root  wheel     584 22 ноя 18:22 /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key.pub
  -rwxrwxr-x   1 root  wheel    3169  1 янв  2020 /etc/ssh/sshd_config
  ```

How can this be fixed? I really need your help! I'm desperate :(

Comment: What's the point of `ssh localhost`? You are already on the system, so... why SSH?

Comment: Are you sure you only edited `/etc/hosts`? Perhaps you changed the permissions of files and directories in `/etc`? What does `ls -ld /etc /etc/ssh* /etc/ssh*/*` show (please add it to your question)

Comment: @roaima I add output of ls -ld /etc /etc/ssh* /etc/ssh*/*

Comment: I need to check my Mac tomorrow but those permissions look really suspect. Are you sure you didn't accidently use `chmod` while working as root?

Comment: @roaima No, I'm not sure. Maybe I use it. I don't remember. But how can I fix it?
Now I have this eror: 
`kex_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer  
Connection reset by ::1 port 22`

Answer (score 1):

You have broken the permissions for (at least) the files in `/etc`, and this is why `ssh` is no longer working. Here is a correct set for the files you've listed in your question:

```
lrwxr-xr-x@  1 root  wheel      11  1 Jan  2020 /etc -> private/etc
drwxr-xr-x  13 root  wheel     416 22 Nov 12:22 /etc/ssh
-rw-r--r--   1 root  wheel  577388  1 Jan  2020 /etc/ssh/moduli
-rw-r--r--   1 root  wheel    1511  1 Jan  2020 /etc/ssh/ssh_config
-rw-------   1 root  wheel     672 18 Jun  2018 /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
-rw-r--r--   1 root  wheel     590 18 Jun  2018 /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key.pub
-rw-------   1 root  wheel     227 18 Jun  2018 /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
-rw-r--r--   1 root  wheel     162 18 Jun  2018 /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key.pub
-rw-------   1 root  wheel     387 18 Jun  2018 /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
-rw-r--r--   1 root  wheel      82 18 Jun  2018 /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key.pub
-rw-------   1 root  wheel    1679 18 Jun  2018 /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
-rw-r--r--   1 root  wheel     382 18 Jun  2018 /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key.pub
-rw-r--r--   1 root  wheel    3169  1 Jan  2020 /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

My suspicion is that you may have changed more permissions than these.

Unfortunately I have found conflicting and unclear documents on the correct method for correcting permissions on system files, so I would recommend you go across to https://apple.stackexchange.com/ and see whether the question on fixing permissions has previously been asked - and answered - there. (You don't need to ask specifically how to fix `ssh` - that will be resolved once you've fixed the permissions.)